# Code Generator HTTPie

Tags: paw-app, httpie

I have two requests in Paw -

The first is GET request authorization/login that returns a dynamic value in the Raw body.

The second is a POST that uses the first request's raw body dynamic value as a header value.

The code generator (using HTTPie) does not account for the dynamic changing value in the second request- How do I resolve this issue?

How can I solve this issue?

Simply put, the workflow requires a total of two requests for each time I want to run it. (1 Authorization and 1 for Data) I wanted to run the entire workflow as two separate shell scripts using HTTPie

Comment: I don't really understand what's happening. I have set in a request a Request Raw body dynamic value, pointing to another request, and I get the right result in this request's header: https://www.evernote.com/shard/s93/sh/21f3de98-2b2e-4a52-8e8a-bf35d6390256/2ca7a5c65fd71fec can you explain a little more about your flow? possibly with screenshots? thank you!

Comment: @MichaMazaheri here is [screen shot](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/49569672/Screen%20Shot%202016-04-14%20at%2011.22.57%20PM.png?raw=1)